# Can't navigate to UITabBarController

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation, uitabbarcontroller

After login from my system it should navigate to HomeController from LoginController. But after successfully login it doesn't continue to navigate my HomeController. My HomeController is using UITabBarController.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Ca6.png)

```
guard let navController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController else { return }
guard let controller = navController.viewControllers[0] as? HomeController else { return }
controller.configureViewComponents()

controller.loadUserData()

self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Have you checked that those returns on the guard conditions are not being executed? The `tabbarcontroller` is already presented?

Comment: @Claudio it can print "Login successful-1" on my console, it just didn't navigate to HomeController page on my system.

Comment: If you add a print statement after the `controller.configureViewComponents()` is it printed?

Comment: @Claudio no, it doesn't print. Even add statement before ' controller.configureViewComponents() ' it also didn't print anything.

Comment: That's because one of the two `guard` conditions is failing

Comment: @Claudio can I know is there any navigate method can use to navigate it???